# android- How to impaneled a searchview for map with String and Lat lang?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, searchview

I want to have a searchview for my map that is based on the name of and the Latlang of the location.

I have a Hashmap();

but this line:
  map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);

gives the error: **Wrong 2nd argument type, required String, Found Latlang.**

I tried to change the   BaseColumns._ID to Latlang but I couldn't.

How can I fix this?

```
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

//The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final Latlang KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,Latlang> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context The Context within which to work, used to create the DB
 */
public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

private static HashMap<String,Latlang> buildColumnMap() {
    HashMap<String,Latlang> map = new HashMap<String,Latlang>();
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: How about `map.put(BaseColumns._ID, new Latlang(data1, data2));`? Or Why can't you just create a `Map<String, String>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the map as:

```
HashMap<String,Latlang> map = new HashMap<String,Latlang>();
```

However, your data are strings:

```
map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
```

I suggest you declare the map like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Or make sure your values are actually LatLng:

```
map.put(BaseColumns._ID, new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```

Comment: I did some more coding and ran the app and now it gives this error  **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference**
on this line: `new LatLng(latitude, longitude));`

Comment: If you'd notice LatLng gets two doubles in its constructor. What you are doing is giving it a Double object (capital D on purpose) which is null. I suggest you initialize it and be sure you are not calling new LatLng(latitude, longitude) too early with no data.

Comment: I initialized it but I'm not sure I'm calling it in the right place.
Is calling it in the `buildColumnMap` method right?